# Overlapping columns in 2 cols RWD

Tags: html, css

Why are the columns overlapping when you decrease the browser width? Where's the point?

Link: http://lubuskiespa.pl/fitness/

Comment: Welcome, @jumpelzg. You'll have better success getting your question answered if you can explain what you have tried so far that isn't working. Be specific. See "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it does not fit the table.

you must use

```
table {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

And for device with size smaller than 1000px, I advice use @media query.
In your case,try it :

```
@media (max-width:1000px) {
   .span_1_of_2 {
       width: 100%;
   }
}
```